# Kendo UI dynamic spreadsheet

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use the Kendo Spreadsheet.  What I am trying to accomplish is this...I have dynamic data coming in.  When a user clicks a button it displays the data as either a chart or spreadsheet based on which is currently displayed, by default it is the chart.  The data structure is all the same just the values are different.  I created a function that builds the data and creates spreadsheet.

```
function bob(data){
    var rows = massageData();
    $('.' + element).kendoSpreadsheet({
        toolbar: false,
        sheetsbar: false,
        sheets: [{
            name: name.Title,
            rows: rows
        }]
    });
}
```

I call a function bob (arbitrary name) every minute.  The chart, by default, loads and the spreadsheet loads just fine initially.  I can see this by clicking on a button to toggle the view between chart and spreadsheet.  However, if the chart is being displayed when the data comes in the spreadsheet is blank (no values) when I make the spreadsheet visible. I have to wait for the update again and then the spreadsheet updates properly. Here is the kicker, if the spreadsheet is visible when the update comes in everything loads fine. Why is the spreadsheet not loading properly if it is hidden?  I am only using CSS to add a hidden class that sets display to none.

Comment: The spreadsheet might not be rendered after data is getting populated. Just try:

`var spreadsheet = $('.' + element).data("kendoSpreadsheet");
spreadsheet.render();`

Comment: @AaBa When I run that I get Uncaught TypeError: spreadsheet.render is not a function(…)

Comment: Render is one of the function mentioned in the API - not sure, why that wont work. But good to hear, refresh method did the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the CSS call display: none; removed it from the DOM and it wasn't being rendered properly.  When I did a

```
$('.' + element).data("kendoSpreadsheet").refresh();
```

That did the trick.